# how i can add this tool in pagespeed insights to my web

Tags: javascript, blogger, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I want to learn how to add this tool to my blog in blogger

[image]

and thank you very much

Comment: what do you mean that tool, page speed insights or the idea of the first contentful paint and first input delay

Comment: i mean "First Contentful Paint (FCP)" and "First Input Delay (FID)" don't show

Comment: Neither of them appears when I do a speed test for my blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve these metrics using the Lighthouse audit under the 'Audits' panel in the Chrome dev tools, with at least the Performance test checked.

[image: Lighthouse Audit Result]

Comment: i don't understand u .. i want add tools in my blog only .. :)

Comment: Do you want to measure FCP and FID for your blog, or add your own pagespeed test to your blog?

Comment: i want add  page speed test to my blog